# FOS Elastic range price with discount

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I want to get all the products by range price with discount.

this is what it looks like in sql:

```
  WHERE (
CASE WHEN p.discount IS NOT NULL THEN ROUND(
  p.unit_price * (100 - p.discount) / 100, 1) 
ELSE p0_.unit_price END ) >= :min 
  AND (
    CASE WHEN p.discount IS NOT NULL THEN ROUND(
      p.unit_price * (100 - p.discount) / 100, 1) 
    ELSE p0_.unit_price END ) <= :max
```

is there a way to do the same with range condition?

```
$fieldRange = new \Elastica\Query\Range('unitPrice', array('gte' => 300, 'lte' => 1500));
```

here is my config:

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { url: '%env(ELASTICSEARCH_URL)%' }
    indexes:
        product:
               properties:
                   unitPrice:
                       type: integer
                   discount:
                       type: keyword
                   attributeValues:
                       type: "nested"
                       properties:
                           value:
                               type: keyword
                           product:
                               type: keyword
           persistence:
               driver: orm
               model: App\Entity\Product
               provider: ~
               listener: ~
               finder: ~
```

here is the full query:

```
    $query = new \Elastica\Query();
    $query->setSize(0);

    $boolQuery = new \Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();

  /* filter checked */
    $fieldQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Match();
    $fieldQuery->setFieldQuery('attributeValues.value', 'Brand');
    $domainQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Nested();
    $domainQuery->setPath('attributeValues');
    $domainQuery->setQuery($fieldQuery);

    $fieldQuery2 = new \Elastica\Query\Match();
    $fieldQuery2->setFieldQuery('attributeValues.value', 'Another Brand');
    $domainQuery2 = new \Elastica\Query\Nested();
    $domainQuery2->setPath('attributeValues');
    $domainQuery2->setQuery($fieldQuery2);

    $fieldRange = new \Elastica\Query\Range('unitPrice', array('gte' => 300, 'lte' => 1500));


    $boolQuery->addMust($domainQuery);
    $boolQuery->addMust($domainQuery2);
    $boolQuery->addMust($fieldRange);

    $query->setQuery($boolQuery);

    $agg = new \Elastica\Aggregation\Nested('attributeValues', 'attributeValues');
    $names = new \Elastica\Aggregation\Terms('value');
    $cardinality = new \Elastica\Aggregation\Cardinality('unique_products');

    $cardinality->setField('attributeValues.product');
    $names->setField('attributeValues.value');
    $names->setSize(100);

    $names->addAggregation($cardinality);
    $agg->addAggregation($names);
    $query->addAggregation($agg);



    $companies = $this->finder->findPaginated($query);
    $asd = $companies->getAdapter()->getAggregations();
```

here is the result:

```
        array(
    "attributeValues" => array:2(
        "doc_count" => 406,
        "value" => array:3(
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" => 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" => 0,
            "buckets" => array:42(
                2 => array:3(
                    "key" => "Another Brand",
                    "doc_count" => 15,
                    "unique_products" => array:1(
                        "value" => 9
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

here is native request (just in case):

```
{
"size": 0,
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "attributeValues",
                    "query": {
                        "match": {
                            "attributeValues.value": {
                                "query": "Brand"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "attributeValues",
                    "query": {
                        "match": {
                            "attributeValues.value": {
                                "query": "Another Brand"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "range": {
                    "unitPrice": {
                        "gte": 300,
                        "lte": 1500
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "attributeValues": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "attributeValues"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "value": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "attributeValues.value",
                    "size": 100
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "unique_products": {
                        "cardinality": {
                            "field": "attributeValues.product"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

a little explanation - I am making a smart filter that disables options when there are no products in it, which I calculate with this query. But I don't know how to calculate the price range with a discount (%) in elastica. I show how I do it in sql.

Comment: can you share your index mapping, sample docs and expected result, basic range query can on a single field can easily be applied , refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

Comment: @Elasticsearch Ninja ok i post it in answer. sorry my mistake.

Comment: You mean in question??

Comment: @Elasticsearch Ninja sorry forgot about the edit button

Comment: @Elasticsearch Ninja  When I tried to find information on how to do this, I found a theme in magento (cms) there was some problem with the price slider, but this is not the main thing. there was an example of a database with several fields for the price, for example - price, final_price (always filled in and changes depending on the availability of discounts, coupons), max_price, min_price. And the following question arises: is it possible to calculate the price on the fly in elastic, or do you need to add extra fields to the database?